# Как сделать так, чтобы приложение реагировало на поворот экрана смартфона?

Tags: java, android, orientation

Написанное мной приложение, по какой-то причине, никак не реагирует на поворот (изменение ориентации) экрана (насколько я знаю, при повороте экрана, по умолчанию, активность должна уничтожаться и создаваться заново, однако этого не происходит).
Создал даже layout-land в ресурсах, в качестве альтернативной директории, не помогает (я знаю, что просто создание директории помочь и не может, однако я вообще не понимаю причину возникновения проблемы).

Манифест:

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".QuizActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Проверьте, что у вас на девайсе поворот экрана не отключён. Если отключён - покажите манифест - может там у вас запрет на поворот стоит.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я проверял не только на физическом устройстве, но и на эмуляторе

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, манифест добавил

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, проблема была и правда в запрете поворота на физическом устройстве (почему на эмуляторе не работает, не знаю)
Огромное Вам спасибо!